# What should we do with useless, but answered, questions

Tags: discussion, questions, review

I was reviewing Late Answers when I stumbled on this question:

[Imported tables are not showing up in phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539589/imported-tables-are-not-showing-up-in-phpmyadmin)

To sum up, the problem is: *I dumped data in a MySQL database using a script, but it's not showing up in PHPMyAdmin*. The OP answered his own question and said: *Nevermind, hosting guys changed the database location*.

It is not the first time I see such a question / answer and I am not sure what to do with them. For instance, I remembered a question about a PHP/Curl script not working as expected, and after helping with debugging, it turned out that Curl was not installed.

In the current case, I'm asked to review [this late answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12235512/1229260) which clearly makes no sense in regards to what was answered by the post owner.

Should I flag the answer, since it's irrelevant? Should I also cast a close vote as "Too localized" on the question? Or should I flag the question for moderator attention, so it can be deleted? The question itself in not necessarily too localized, but the answer makes it useless, in my opinion, it adds no value to SO.

Comment: Flag the question as too localized and move on.

Comment: The PHP/Curl script question with the answer being Curl not installed, is potentially super helpful (especially if you don't have Curl installed)....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future reference I will quote Martijn Pieters' comment, which is in my opinion the perfect way to deal with this situation:

> Flag the question as too localized and move on.

Answer (score 3):

The answer would be useful to someone who was not finding their database in PHPMyAdmin and missed the announcement about the change in database location.

What's useless to some people may be very useful to others.

Comment: But I don't think it belongs in SO in that case. I think it is very important to do some research before asking a question. On in my opinion this type of question is as relevant as asking "Why does PHP say I have a parse error in my script" when there is a missing semicolon in the source code.